# class value of data-menu-position in jPanelMenu

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to add a class to an element depending on the value of `jPanelMenu`'s `data-menu-position`.

I'm building a mobile site using the plugin and my header is like so :

```
View menu | --------Branding-------- | Login
```

When my `jPanelMenu` is open, I can't click on the `View menu` button -- when I do, I'm redirected to another page, either the page linked from my `Branding` area, or from my `Login` link. In both cases, it closes the menu, but I am redirected, as opposed to seeing the current page.

I have tried using `z-index`, without any luck. I've also tried something like this, but nothing worked:

```
$('#view_menu').addClass( $('body').attr('data-menu-position') );
```

The idea was to change the `href` to `#` once the menu was open so I couldn't be redirected, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Has anyone come across this kind of issue, or did anyone find any solutions (ajax, jquery...) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so here's what I did :

```
$(document).ready(
function()
{
  // set default state from menu position attribute
});
$('#menu_btn').click(function()
{
  if($('body').attr("data-menu-position") == 'closed')
  {
    // user clicked -> what to do on open  }
  else
  {
    // user clicked -> what to do on close  }
});
```

Exactly as expected. Using `jquery` `if` statements, I could check the of the `data-menu-position` value and remove my links like so :

```
$('#menu_btn').click(function()
{
    if($('body').attr("data-menu-position") == 'closed')
    {
        if($('body').attr("data-menu-position") == 'closed')
        {
            $("#menu_btn a").attr("href", "#");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure as to what the actual problem stems from since I've never used jPanelMenu perhaps the problem lies elsewhere.
However, I can help achieve the 'workaround' you're suggesting.

```
$('#view_menu').click( function() {
  $(this).children('a[data-menu-position=foobar]').attr('href','#');
});
```

Essentially, you click the element with id 'view_menu', and scans it's children for an anchor with the attribute 'data-menu-position' which has 'foobar' as it's value. (You could replace foobar with a variable) and then changes that anchor's href to a '#'

Obviously the structure might not be the same so I think you'll be able to figure out the rest.
If the anchor is not a direct child of the id, then you can use 'find' instead of 'children'.

You can test it here: http://d.pr/VeGB/5KtUUeMT